# Media Encoder or Premiere Pro get stuck while exporting

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe

I have the latest version of Premiere Pro and Media Encoder.. But while exporting a project after processing for a few seconds it doesn't progress further and my GPU usage is at 100%-0% and again to 100%. It is like a spike in the Task Manager? Can anybody help me with this?

[image]

Comment: It's probably best to contact Adobe. Before, check if the graphics card is supported by Adobe, try the newest or a slightly old version of it's driver, try to export the same project on a different machine: if the same problems occurs, some of the clips used in the sequence could be the reason. Check if their format is fully supported, or if they are damaged. Maybe try to convert individual clips with ffmpeg in command line and see if any warning messages appear. Look for anything unusual. Disable plugins, maybe even disable complex effects. These measures all help to isolate the problem.

Comment: Anyway, it's unlikely anybody can answer this question as there are just too many things to check. And in case it's some hardware problem, it cannot be investigated without having direct access to your system.